# LXD ZFS Storage Pool на другом диске

Tags: linux, lxc, контейнеры, zfs

В общем, есть zfs пул для LXD, настроенный командой `lxd init` и находящийся на системном SSD диске. Однако мне нужно также хранить файлы в контейнерах.

Вопрос: как создать zfs пул для lxd, находящийся на другом диске (hdd). Или же есть другой способ хранения данных в контейнере на hdd?